# What does generate_anchor_base()'s arguments mean?

Tags: chainer, chainercv

[Github page](https://github.com/chainer/chainercv/blob/master/chainercv/links/model/faster_rcnn/utils/generate_anchor_base.py)

Looking `generate_anchor_base` method, which is Faster R-CNN util method in ChainerCV.

What is the `base_size = 16`?  I saw in the Documentation that it is

> The width and the height of the reference window.

But what does "reference window" mean?

Also it says that `anchor_scales=[8, 16, 32]` are the areas of the anchors but I thought that that the areas are (128, 256, 512)

Another question:
If the `base size` is 16 and `h = 128` and `w=128`, Does that mean `anchor_base[index, 0] = py - h / 2` is a negative value?
since py = 8 and and h/2 = 128/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is a util function of Faster R-CNN, so I assume you understood what is the "anchor" proposed in Faster R-CNN.

- "Faster R-CNN: Towards Real-Time Object Detection with Region Proposal Networks" https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.01497

`base_size` and `anchor_scales` determines the size of the anchor. 
For example, when `base_size=16` and `anchor_scales=[8, 16, 32]` (and `ratio=1.0`), height and width of the anchor will be `16 * [8, 16, 32] = (128, 256, 512)`, as you expected.
`ratio` determines the height and width aspect ratio.

(I might be wrong in below paragraph, please correct if I'm wrong.)

I think `base_size` need to be set as the size of the current hidden layer's scale. In the `chainercv` Faster R-CNN implementation, `extractor`'s feature is fed into `rpn` (region proposal network) and `generate_anchor_base` is used in `rpn`. So you need to take care what is the feature of `extractor`'s output. `chainercv` uses VGG16 as the feature extractor, and `conv5_3` layer is used as extracted feature (see [here](https://github.com/chainer/chainercv/blob/master/chainercv/links/model/faster_rcnn/faster_rcnn_vgg.py#L109)), this layer is a place where `max_pooling_2d` is applied 4 times, which results 2^4=16 times smallen feature.

For the another question, I think your understanding is correct, `py - h / 2` will be negative value. But this `anchor_base` value is just a relative value. Once `anchor_base` is prepared at the initialization of model ([here](https://github.com/chainer/chainercv/blob/master/chainercv/links/model/faster_rcnn/region_proposal_network.py#L55-L56)), actual (absolute value) `anchor` is created in each forward call ([here](https://github.com/chainer/chainercv/blob/master/chainercv/links/model/faster_rcnn/region_proposal_network.py#L116-L117)) in `_enumerate_shifted_anchor` method.

Comment: Yes, thank you. 16 is the receptive field(in the original image) for every spatial location in "conv5_3". But I still can't get it, Why do we need to create variable "base_size"? We could just say anchor_scales=[128, 256, 512], right? What does the operation mean "base size * anchor_scales"? What does "reference window" mean? So sorry for all those questions :(